# Html & Php code inside a returned variable

Tags: php, woocommerce

Is it possible to return a variable from a php file that includes a combination of html & php code and a shortcode, that will be used and run in a woocommerce product description?

(I have an extension installed that allow execution of php code inside the wysiwyg editor)

The code that i have so far is:

```
function age ($example) {

$x = "<b>Alter:</b> [insert_php]global $product; $dobs = get_the_terms( $product->id, "pa_geburtsdatum"); foreach ($dobs as $dob) { $from = new DateTime($dob->name); $to = new DateTime("today"); echo $from->diff($to)->y; }[/insert_php]";

return $x;
}
```

UPDATE:
I have created a custom shortcode, doing all the calculation behind the scenes, which is way more comfortable and secure. In between the shortcode I have the dob, and the age is then given back after calculating it with a specific function.

Comment: First you need to extract the string between `[insert_php]` and `[/insert_php]` and then use php `eval` function to execute the code.

Comment: I don't want to execute it right now. The  code (html+php+shortcode) needs to be transferred exactly as it is to my woocommerce product short description.

Comment: There are times `eval()` is useful, but seeing you don't even fully understand string escaping, I can only conclude 1 thing. You do ***not*** comprehend security and why on earth would you use run PHP code for a description? My answer for you, No. There is no way.

Comment: Because i have a date of birth as product attribute (my products are people), and this gets transformed into the current age

Comment: What about htmlspecialchars();

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ever-unsafe and incredibly dangerous `eval()` function to take the value of your shortcode and run it as PHP.  This will run anything you pass to it as PHP, so:

```
eval('global $product; $dobs = get_the_terms( $product->id, "pa_geburtsdatum"); foreach ($dobs as $dob) { $from = new DateTime($dob->name); $to = new DateTime("today"); echo $from->diff($to)->y; }');
```

would produce the output you're looking for.  [pontification]I stress, however, that this would be a terrible idea on a forward-facing site.[/pontification]  If it were me (and it's not, to each their own), I'd make a shortcode that took the arguments you want to work with and process them behind the scenes.

Comment: Actually I need exact this phrase that will then be included in the short description of a woocommerce product. And if the productpage opens the shortcode runs the php.

Comment: Okay, but how do i get my shortcode back? The php must be running at the product page because of the specific attribute this calculation uses.

Comment: The shortcode should return whatever the output of whatever you sent to eval()

Comment: Okay, but how to i get the html, the shortcode and the output of eval() in my $x and return it?

Comment: I was following your tip and created a custom shortcode, which was a way better plan than my initial. There is this great resource about how to do it: https://www.sitepoint.com/custom-shortcodes-for-wordpress/